# Data binding build error, extraneous input '\r' expecting {COMMENT, SEA_WS, '<', PI}

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I had this error on 2 different days and wasted the better part of both trying to find a solution. At best, I found temporary work-arounds rather than permanent solutions. The actual problem may even be a bug in Android Studio.

**My Problem**: I have an Android Studio project that stopped building correctly after I updated AS to 2.3.0. The project uses Google data-binding in its layout files, Android Gradle plugin 2.3.0, Gradle 2.4.1. The error received is in the dataBindingProcessLayoutsDebug task complaining about extraneous input character, '\r' which is the old-style mac line ending.

After looking at my layout files in another text editor I noticed that some of my layout files contained the wrong line endings, '\r', instead of '\n'. I opened the Preferences in Android Studio, looked at the setting under Editor -> Code and noticed the setting of classic mac.  I use a number of JetBrain products and have never explicitly set or changed this setting.

Comment: did you get any solution for this?i am also facing same problem

Comment: yes, it turned out that the file contained both carriage return characters (ASCII 0x13) and line feed characters (ASCII 0x10). As explained below, in Android Studio, look at the bottom-right portion of the status bar for a "LF", "LF/CR", or "CR". It should only be "LF" when running android studio on a mac.

Answer (score 3):

A really easy way to tell what the line endings are in your files in AS: Look at the bottom of the IDE next to the line/column display to find, hopefully, LF. Click this dropdown to the select the correct line ending for your platform.

[image]

So, if your AS project is breaking due to extraneous input, try looking at the line endings of your layout files.